# Install newer version of gstreamer on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, gstreamer, vaapi

i have Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-104-generic. And i have gstreamer1.0 version 1.8.3.

how can i install gstreamer version 1.9.x on my Ubuntu version?

because i need to use GStreamer/gstreamer-vaapi and the requirement are following:

### Requirements

Software requirements

- GStreamer 1.9.x:
    libgstreamer1.0-dev (>= 1.9.x)
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev (>= 1.9.x)
    libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev (>= 1.9.0)
- Renderers:
    DRM: libva-dev (>= 1.1.0), libdrm-dev, libudev-dev
    X11: libva-dev (>= 1.0.1)
    GLX: libva-dev (>= 1.0.3)
    Wayland: libva-dev (>= 1.1.0), libwayland-dev (>= 1.0.2)

Best Regards.